# ! LaTeX Error: You have run the document with pdflatex, but PSTricks

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

I get some error when  run my latex file: please help me.

! LaTeX Error: You have run the document with pdflatex, but PSTricksrequires latex->dvips->ps2pdf or alternatively the useof the package `auto-pst-pdf'. Then you can run`pdflatex -shell-escape ' (TeX Live)or`pdflatex -enable-write18 ' (MikTeX).See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin{document}

Comment: All is said in the error message, you have some pstricks code that cannot be compiled by pdflatex alone. You must load the `auto-pst-pdf` package, and launch pdflatex with one of the mentioned switches. We can help more if you give some more details (which distribution do you have, which editor, &c.)

Comment: You are using Sage-TeX. Instaed of running `pdflatex` use `xelatex` and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error message is pretty clear as it stands. The package `PSTricks` does not run with `pdflatex` without additional preparations (like including the package `auto-pst-pdf` and adding some operating system dependend compilation flag), but only with standard latex producing a `dvi` file. This `dvi` file is converted to a `ps` (PostScript) file with `dvips`. In a last step you can get a `pdf` file from the `ps` file running either `ps2pdf` or `pstopdf` (the latter two are two different programs producing different pdf files that should look the same on screen and on paper).

Comment: You *can* compile with pdflatex if you load `auto-pst-pdf`.

Comment: @Bernard: OK, I rephrased my answer. My main aim in the answer was to guide the classical LaTeX-dvips-ps2pdf path.